# How to change cell value dynamically in ListView with GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have used the GridView inside the ListView. I want to dynamically change a cell value. For example, there is a column named "Time", I wanna to change this value when something happens. I can find and get the cell (e.g `od.Time` as in following codes), **but can not change its value**. Some codes like this where `ObjectData` is the class for all ListView columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      ObjectData od = (ObjectData)objectListView.Items[i];
      if (od.UserName == "Tom")
      {
          od.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Is your listview bound to a data source?

Comment: yes, i have bound to a data source in .xaml file. such as <GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the your listview is bound to a data source you'll need to change the data source's data, not the listview's contents. It should then update the listview.

Comment: @TomJacky - Are you binding it to a list of objects? If so, look at using an Observable collection to automate the refresh: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx